# how to get or put string to clipboard in c# .netcore put string to clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, clipboard

I am building a .net core console application that requires interaction with the clipboard. How can I put a simple string to clipboard, and get string from clipboard in .net core?

I currently tried to import `System.Windows.Forms` and use its function, but it doesn't seem to let me do that, since the library seems to be working on windows only.

```
using System.Windows.Forms

...
Clipboard.SetText()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to put string to clipboard in .NET Core is to use the small TextCopy nuget package

```
Install-Package TextCopy
```

and

```
TextCopy.ClipboardService.SetText("any string");
```